# how to get Multiple Array attribute values into a csv file

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have below sample data . and my code is as below

Code :

Sample Data:

```
{
  "data": [
  {
      "IdNo": "1234",
      "Name": "ABC",
       "Distribution": {
          "Section": [
            {
              "SectionName": {
                "id": "S1234"
              }
            }
          ],
          "Identity": [
            {
              "SectionName": {
                "id": "S5678"
              }
            },
            {
              "SectionName": {
                "id": "S7878"
              }
            }
          ]
          }

     }
     ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(json_file['data'])):
    temp = {}
    temp['IdNo'] = json_file['data'][i]['IdNo']
    temp['Name'] = json_file['data'][i]['Name']
    for key in json_file['data'][i]['Distribution'].keys():
        try:
            for j in range(len(json_file['data'][i]['Distribution'][key])):
                temp[key]  = json_file['data'][i]['Distribution'][key][j]['SectionName']['id'] 
        except:
            temp[key] = None                    
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame([temp])
        df = pd.concat([df, temp_df], sort=True)
```

i am getting only 1 record in the ouput

```
IdNo     Name       Section     Identity
1234     Abc        S1234       S7878
```

Please help me with any suggestion how can i achieve below output
But i am trying to achieve below output.

```
IdNo     Name           Section         Identity
1234     Abc            S1234           S5678
1234     Abc                            S7878
```

Comment: got some indenting problems there

Comment: @Will .. I have re-edited the question. Please please have a look

Comment: The indenting in your code is wonky. Impossible to know how the for loops are structured

Comment: The data structures inside "Distribution" are different lengths. How do you want to get your desired output?

Comment: @Will . I added the expected output. At the last with 2 records...

Comment: I am getting one record as per my code. But i am trying to achieve 2 records..

Comment: Your code, with its current indenting, will not run.

Comment: In json_file, "Section" only has one element in the list while in "Identity" there are 2 elements in the list. How are you expected to interpret that? Should they share the same ["Section"]["id"]?

Comment: @Will both are different keys and i am trying to read them as keys. like ["Section"]["id"] & ["Identity"]["id"].

Comment: @Will .. Help me with any suggestion

Comment: problem is you have 1 Section and 2 Identities. How do you want to match them? We cannot guess your use case.